# Layer to KML data interoperability error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-interoperability, layer-to-kml

I have a 2D raster dataset that I am trying to convert to KML (using the Layer to KML tool in ArcGIS desktop) for display in Esri Earth, but no matter what I try as the inputs, I keep getting a data interoperability error.  I've tried using a raster layer both within a file gdb and outside of a file gdb thinking this could be causing the issue, nope.  I'm using the defaults for the optional parameters:

[image]

Any idea why this isn't working??

code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <metadata xml:lang="en"><Esri><CreaDate>20170612</CreaDate><CreaTime>1‌​7164000</CreaTime><A‌​rcGISFormat>1.0</Arc‌​GISFormat><ArcGISsty‌​le>ISO 19139 Metadata Implementation Specification</ArcGISstyle><SyncOnce>TRUE</SyncOnce><DataPro‌​perties><lineage><Pr‌​ocess ToolSource="c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\Conversion Tools.tbx\LayerToKML" Date="20170612" Time="171640">LayerToKML Inundation_ft E:\MP\Inundation_ft_LayerToKML.kmz 0 false # 1024 96 CLAMPED_TO_GROUND</Process></lineage></DataProperties></Esri‌​></metadata>
```

Comment: can we see the kml xml?

Comment: I don't have an xml.  I am trying to convert this using the Layer to KML tool in ArcGIS desktop

Comment: KML is an xml file do a view source in or open in notepad++ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language

Comment: I thought I could add an attachment to my original post, but that doesn't appear to be the case so I have to just post what is in the KML file:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata xml:lang="en"><Esri><CreaDate>20170612</CreaDate><CreaTime>17164000</CreaTime><ArcGISFormat>1.0</ArcGISFormat><ArcGISstyle>ISO 19139 Metadata Implementation Specification</ArcGISstyle><SyncOnce>TRUE</SyncOnce><DataProperties><lineage><Process ToolSource="c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\Conversion Tools.tbx\LayerToKML" Date="20170612" Time="171640">LayerToKML Inundation_ft E:\MP\Inundation_ft_LayerToKML.kmz 0 false # 1024 96 CLAMPED_TO_GROUND</Process></lineage></DataProperties></Esri></metadata>

Comment: did it create a kmz file in your e drive?  called Inundation_ft_LayerToKML.kmz?

Comment: yes. Initially I didn't even try to open it b/c I got that error when it processed (my bad).  But I just tried and it opens.  Resolution is really bad compared to what it is in ArcMap.  I have 3m horizontal resolution there.

Comment: Perhaps AGOL is the better solution